# YA Book about a village girl who runs away with 2 friends

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

hiya this book has been PLAGUING my mind for over 6 years; it’s been so long i am beginning to doubt the little details that i know:/ **It is a definitely book for teenagers with the genre of dystopian/fantasy/maybe sci-fi.**

The plot is centred around a girl ( main character-mc). She is in a dystopian village that she dislikes due to an arranged marriage, and runs away with her two friends. There is a boy around her age who is the head scout/hunting leader?? who is told by the village to track them down?
**The most specific thing I remember is that he called her “tree rat".**
Although they are ahead of hunters in the forest, they are weakened by starvation. Then the mc dreams something that her mum???? (or previous guardian) told her about a plant that can be eaten and it turns out to be true.

The rest is not so clear to me; the mc and her two friends meet some a village of witches/magic practices? and they band together with the village that they had escaped from, for battle.

**In the ending, the mc falls in love with the boy from her village (who was meant to track her down and kill her).**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the names of any of the characters or the places they visit?  Was it a hardcover, paperback, or e-book?  Where did you get it?  Any recollection of the cover art?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.